# Can we fit a model using the same dataset applied during cross validation process?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, cross-validation

I have the following method that performs Cross Validation on a dataset followed by a final model fit:

```
import numpy as np
import utilities.utils as utils
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.utils import shuffle

def CV(args, path):

    df = pd.read_csv(path + 'HIGGS.csv', sep=',')
    df = shuffle(df)
    df_labels = df[df.columns[0]]
    df_features = df.drop(df.columns[0], axis=1)
    clf = MLPClassifier(hidden_layer_sizes=(64, 64, 64),
                        activation='logistic',
                        solver='adam',
                        learning_rate_init=1e-3,
                        max_iter=1000,
                        batch_size=1000,
                        learning_rate='adaptive',
                        early_stopping=True
                        )

    print('\t >>> Start Cross Validation ... ')
    scores = cross_val_score(estimator=clf, X=df_features, y=df_labels, cv=5, n_jobs=-1)
    print("CV Accuracy: %0.2f (+/- %0.2f)\n\n" % (scores.mean(), scores.std() * 2))


    # Final Fit
    print('\t >>> Start Final Fit ... ')
    num_to_read = (int(10999999) * (args.stages * np.dtype(np.float64).itemsize))
    C1 = utils.read_from_disk(path + 'HIGGS.dat', 0, num_to_read, args.stages)
    print(C1)
    print(C1.shape)
    r = C1[:, :1]
    C = np.delete(C1, 0, axis=1)

    tr_C, ts_C, tr_r, ts_r = train_test_split(C, r, train_size=.8)
    clf.fit(tr_C, tr_r)
    prd_r = clf.predict(ts_C)
    test_acc = accuracy_score(ts_r, prd_r) * 100.

    return test_acc
```

I understand that Cross Validation is about evaluating how well your model is with a given dataset. My questions are:

1. Is it logically correct to fit the model again by the same dataset I used during the cross validation process?
2. During each CV fold, are the model parameters carried out to the next fold? For instance, in the case of Neural Network, is the fitted model from fold=1 carried out to fold=2?
3. Does this process (I mean fitting the entire dataset as I did above) produce a model accuracy near to the average accuracy we get after cross validation?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

R1. At the very end when you are performing CV you are splitting your dataset into k-sets and each time your are going to train your set with k-1 sets and test/validate with the 1/k of the data (different every time).

R2. Every time MLP is performing learning with a set (k-1 small sets) the learning tasks starts again, at the end the average measure of MSE or the error measure is the mean of errors in k different scenarios.

R3. If the class distribution in data is balance results of k-CV and traditional 70/30 splittings will have approximate generalizations. On the other hand, if the dataset is highly unbalance, a k-CV (10) will tend to better learning generalizations than traditional splittings (since data will represent more effectively all or the majority of the problem classes).